how to know an enum class is sorted
how to know an enum class is sorted, for example:

// is sorted:
enum class data
{
    type1 = 2,
    type2 = 3,
    type3 = 4,
    type4 = 5,
    type5 = 6
};
// not sorted:
enum class data
{
    type1 = 3,
    type2 = 2,
    type3 = 4
    type4 = 6,
    type5 = 5
};


Find a way to let the code know if the enum class is sorted. because I want to provide an interface for the user. The interface will help the user to loop the enum element one by one from the enum define. But if the enum class is not sorted, I can't help the user to do this kind of loop and throw an error or give a compile error. For example I have the interface to get a list of enum class:
template<typename Enum>
std::vector<Enum> getEnumList(Enum from, Enum to);

for(const auto& enum : getEnumList(data::type2, data::type4)
{
    /// loop the data type: type2, type3, type4
}

if the enum is sorted, I can get the correct loop: type2, type3, type4
But if the enum is not sorted, the loop is not what I want.
So, I want to know if the enum is sorted, if not, I will throw an error in the interface: getEnumList.

you cant and you should not care

What is the actual problem you have? Why do you need the enumeration to be "sorted"? Please [edit] your question to give us more details and information.

what exaxtly do you mean with "sorted" ? That the names of the enumerators match their values (+1)? Or that the values are listed in increasing order? Both is rather irrelevant. If it is relevant for you, you should explain what for

if you want to check that type1 < type2 && type2 < type3, what prevents you from doing just that?

Also remember that enumerations always start at 0, and then each enumeration name you add will have the previous value plus one. So if you don't explicitly assign values, you will get it "sorted" automatically.

Have a look at C++26 reflections, this may help you getting the enum names and values at compile time: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2996r0.html

moreover a common misunderstanding is that the enumerators would be the only values of the enum, but thats wrong. The whole range of the underlying type is valid values (and its not clear what it would mean for those to be "not sorted"). There are many wrong expectations about enums, what comes much closer as mental image is a type alias imho using data = int;

enum Foo { n, x = 10 }; has a bit-range of 0 to 15.  Note that 1-9 and 11-15 do not have an enumeration identifier.

@S.Gleissner there's also "magic_enum", which does enum reflection (with some limits) on today's compilers :-) I actually use that quite a bit for logging (why print "23", if you can print the actual name instead...), and even the occasional user-visible output.

Added more detail requirement.

with the edit I still do not understand the question. If you want to check from < to why do you not simply do that? I suppose you need a cast to the integer, but otherwise it would just work, no? why not?

I want to provide an interface for the user. The interface will help the user to loop the enum element one by one from the enum define. But if the enum class is not sorted, I can't help the user to do this kind of loop and throw an error or give a compile error.

Merely restating what you already said in the question does not constitute an explanation.

it is still not clear what you mean with "sorted". If from is smaller than to then the values between those two are sorted, simply by construction, because you would increment from in steps of 1 until you reach to. How else would you implement the loop? It is not clear what the issue is that you want to catch. Suppose the loop would be (modulo casting to the underlying type) for (int i = from; i <to ;++i) then you do not need to check anything, it loops from from till to, only if from is bigger then to then there will be 0 iterations, but thats to be expected.

Maybe this could help us understand what you're trying to ask: is enum class data {type1 = 1, type3 = 2, type2 = 3 } sorted or not? Why?

Also: is enum class data {type1 = 1, type2 = 5, type3 = 8 } sorted? Why?

Sounds as if you'd like a std::map with string/int (or int/string) pairs, not an enum. You can initialize it in the code much like you would an enum (even if it is not initialized at compile time).

Thank you all for your answer and sharing. I finally know my request is impossible with current compile environment (c++ 20). But we still get some excellent answers!!!
Hope we can solve it in the future.

There's no way to check the declaration order. Best you can do is check that the constants are contiguous (i.e. there are no gaps in the numbering).
First you start with __PRETTY_FUNCTION__/__FUNSIG__. This lets you check if the enum has a constant with a specific value:
template <auto X>
constexpr const auto &PrettyFuncForValue()
{
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
    return __FUNCSIG__;
    #else
    return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    #endif
}

enum class E
{
    a = 10,
    b = 20,
    c = 21,
    d = 22,
};

// Those outputs here are from Clang, other compilers have something similar.
std::cout << PrettyFuncForValue<E::a>() << '\n'; // const auto &PrettyFuncForValue() [X = E::a]
std::cout << PrettyFuncForValue<E(10)>() << '\n'; // const auto &PrettyFuncForValue() [X = E::a]
std::cout << PrettyFuncForValue<E(11)>() << '\n'; // const auto &PrettyFuncForValue() [X = (E)11]

As you can see, values with associated names result in a different string pattern.
You can then search for this pattern:
template <auto X>
inline constexpr bool enum_constant_is_valid =
    std::string_view(PrettyFuncForValue<X>()).rfind(
        #ifdef _MSC_VER
        "<(enum "
        #else
        "X = ("
        #endif
    ) == std::string_view::npos;

std::cout << enum_constant_is_valid<E::a> << '\n'; // 1
std::cout << enum_constant_is_valid<E(10)> << '\n'; // 1
std::cout << enum_constant_is_valid<E(11)> << '\n'; // 0

Lastly you slap std::integer_sequence onto it to check a range of values:
template <auto A, auto B>
requires std::same_as<decltype(A), decltype(B)>
inline constexpr bool enum_range_is_valid =
    []<std::underlying_type_t<decltype(A)> ...I>(std::integer_sequence<std::underlying_type_t<decltype(A)>, I...>){
        return (enum_constant_is_valid<decltype(A)(std::to_underlying(A) + I)> && ...);
    }(std::make_integer_sequence<std::underlying_type_t<decltype(A)>, std::to_underlying(B) - std::to_underlying(A) + 1>{});

std::cout << enum_range_is_valid<E::a, E::a> << '\n'; // 1
std::cout << enum_range_is_valid<E::a, E::b> << '\n'; // 0
std::cout << enum_range_is_valid<E::b, E::d> << '\n'; // 1

Godbolt link with the full code.

I didnt know that something like PrettyFuncForValue<E::a>() exists. Looks like a pretty cool hack that could also help with enum <-> string.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Yeah, magic_enum uses it for that. Also Boost.PFR uses it to get class member names from member pointers...

Thank you for sharing a good idea. But it still can't work with this example: enum class E { a = 10, b = 20, c = 24, d = 22, e = 21};  Anyway, your answer is pretty cool~


I want to provide an interface for the user. The interface will help
the user to loop the enum element one by one from the enum define. But
if the enum class is not sorted, I can't help the user to do this kind
of loop and throw an error or give a compile error.

Okay, so internally an enum is always sorted.
You don't have to "help" the user to loop/access sequential elements of the enum. Each enum value corresponds to a value like 1, or 2 or ...
The enum value after the one corresponding to 2 is the one corresponding to 3. Always. You can even increment an enum value to get the "next" one...
Does that help you with understanding why your question is weird to people who know how enums work?
If you still have the same issue, you should update your question to help us understand why the sorting of the enum definition is so important (even though we think it's not).

Thanks for your answer. But you can define an enum class that is not sorted. This exactly the root cause why I can't help the user to loop the enum element: enum is sorted "internally", its sequence doesn't follow the definition sometimes.
